# Select Kendo Dropdown with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui, selenium-ide

I am using the Selenium IDE and I cannot select an item from the kendo dropdown menu that I want. Does anybody know how to do this with the Selenium IDE? (or else in C# but I wouldn't be able to test that for a while).

Here's a website that has a dropdown that I was trying to practice on, by trying to assert some of the other dropdown options, no luck. http://derp-bear.herokuapp.com/ui_widgets/kendo_ui_example

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://derp-bear.herokuapp.com/ui_widgets/kendo_ui_example</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.k-input</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=span.k-input</td>
    <td>XL - 7 5/8</td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a traditional `select` drop down. So the dropdown and the options are in 2 different places.

**Drop down arrow** is located in the below code

```
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
</span>
```

Drop down arrow can be selected with the css

```
css=span.k-select
```

**Drop down options** are located in the below location. This section is activated after clicking on the drop down arrow.

```
<ul class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto;" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="size_listbox" aria-live="off">
    <li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">S - 6 3/4</li>
    <li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">M - 7 1/4</li>
    <li class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" id="size_option_selected" aria-selected="true">L - 7 1/8</li>
    <li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">XL - 7 5/8</li>
</ul>
```

Any of the 4 drop down options can be selected with the xpath

```
xpath=//li[@class='k-item'][.='L - 7 1/8']
```

Selenium IDE code will be as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/ui_widgets/kendo_ui_example</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.k-select</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//li[@class='k-item'][.='XL - 7 5/8']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>css=span.k-input</td>
    <td>XL - 7 5/8</td>
</tr>
```

Use `pause` to wait for stuff to load.

Comment: Works perfect! I was having a hard time figuring out how to work with kendo with just Selenium UI. Thanks a million!

Comment: This is the code that worked for me
elmFieldWrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , xpathWrapper)))   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elmFieldWrapper).click(elmFieldWrapper).perform()
time.sleep(1)    
xpathOption = "//ul[@id='scFieldList_{{sc.seq}}_listbox']//li[contains(@class,'k-item')][.='" + strValue + "']"    
elmOption = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , xpathOption)))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elmOption).click(elmOption).perform()
time.sleep(1)